# Access control for adb connection of phone

Tags: android, security, adb, access-control

I need to prevent others from accessing my phone via adb. Any way we can have password protection for adb connection?

Comment: Only specified user should have access to adb shell, THATS my question.

Answer (score 3):

> Since Android 4.2.2, connections to ADB are authenticated with an RSA keypair. This prevents unauthorized use of ADB where the attacker has physical access to a device.

[Security Enhancements in Android 4.3](https://source.android.com/security/enhancements/enhancements43.html)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there's no way to set an extra password specific to adb access.

If you have USB debugging (adb) enabled, on Android 4.3 or later you need to manually accept the host computer on your device before debugging is enabled.

So unless somebody has access and PIN/password to your phone AND the computer you already authorized for USB debugging that phone, your phone should be safe. However, there are security holes such as [this](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/advisories/android-4-4-2-secure-usb-debugging-bypass/) which means that if you're using an old device, maybe it's time for a custom ROM based on a recent version of Android.

With earlier versions of Android, I used an app called Delayed Lock with the ["helper app"](https://www.j4velin.de/dl-root.php) add-on (ROOT required), that automatically enabled/disabled USB debugging when you unlock/lock your phone.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Will look into the details given.

Answer (score -1):

As long as the "USB debugging" ([check it here](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html)) is disabled and phone is locked so no one can have the access to this option, no one can use your phone for adb connection.

Refer [wipe data remotely](https://support.google.com/a/answer/173390?hl=en) for an ill fortunate situation.

Comment: USB debugging can be enabled by connecting to your computer.
What I want is to have a password verification while trying to connect via adb.

Comment: Well, unless it is rooted USB debugging can't be enabled via PC. As far as I know, if your device is rooted, then, even system files can be changed. In that case you won't be able to protect your device.

Comment: Usb debugging can be enabled for normal phones and adb access can be obtained. For doing this package name of launcher/lock application in your phone must be known.